# Displaying all values when Checkbox is unticked Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, checkbox, oracle-apex

I created a checkbox in an interactive report for searching a table in APEX. When a option is checked the correct rows are displayed. However when no checkbox option is selected the search function only returns rows with null values. What I want is for all rows to be returned when no option is selected. How can I do this?

This is the code I used to implement my checkbox
`WHERE  instr(':'||:P20_APP_METHOD||':',application_method)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this?

```
instr(':'||:P20_APP_METHOD||':',application_method) or :P20_APP_METHOD IS NULL
```